# SSIS Script Task Error: exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation

Tags: vb.net, variables, exception, ssis, script-task

I am trying to pass user variables into an SSIS script task to use them in the similarly structured following if clause:-

```
VariableY= Directory.GetFiles(Dts.Variables("User::VarX").Value.ToString, 
"*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)

For Each VarZ In VariableY
If VarZ.ToString.Contains(Dts.Variables("User::Var1").Value.ToString) Then
localVar = 1
End If
```

However upon executing it throws and error of the a vague nature with the statement 'exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation'. Previously in the if clause, the values were being  hard-coded in the contains() function, which executes smoothly. Any suggestions to solve this?

Edit:- [Error Message]

> at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[]
>   arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor) at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj,
>   Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments) at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags
>   invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
>   at System.RuntimeType.InvokeMember(String name, BindingFlags
>   bindingFlags, Binder binder, Object target, Object[] providedArgs,
>   ParameterModifier[] modifiers, CultureInfo culture, String[]
>   namedParams)
>   atMicrosoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTATaskScriptingEngine.ExecuteScript()

Comment: Post the error message. Also, does the directory defined by `User::VarX` exist?

Comment: And does the account running the SSIS package have access to that directory?

Comment: What are you trying to do?  Attempting to convert VarZ to a String seems unlikely to work.

Comment: Yes the directory exists. @Cool_Br33ze

Comment: @Tab Alleman. It was working before I changed the code. The previous code in the If clause is structured like this:-                                                       If VarZ.ToString.Contains("XYZ_String") Then
localVar = 1

Comment: Also I have updated the Problem with the error message. @Cool_Br33ze

Comment: What is the value of `Var1` at run time, and what is the value of `VarZ.ToString` when the error is encountered?

Comment: Value of 'Var1 = FileName' and value of 'VarZ.ToString = FileName_Timestamp' @Tab Alleman

Comment: I don't believe you.   With those values, your issue is not reproducible.   That, or the error is actually occurring in another part of the code you aren't showing.